# How to use conditional formating on a whole row using wildcards in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to create rule in Google Sheet that would format entire row depending on what is the value in specific column. Possible values in this column have prefixes like `REG - completed` and I want to use this prefix to style all data under this prefix. I have tried to use wildcard this way:

`=$F1="REG*"`

...but does not work. I tried to use SEARCH() and FIND() but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula (for `REG` being just in the beginning)

```
=REGEXMATCH(K10,"^REG")
```

OR (if you are interested on `REG` being anywhere)

```
=REGEXMATCH(K10,"REG")
```

[image]

Comment: brilliant! thank you, I was not aware there is regular expresions function there :D